# Ruby on Rails : How to remove Office365 login cookie from browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, azure, cookies

I have developed a Rails application which uses Office365 for Authentication using Oauth2.

My problem is when in i tried to logout from my application and login again i will be redirected to my application without going to office 365 login page. I tried to remove cache and tried to login again it will move to office 365 login page.

Is it possible to remove office 365 login cookie/session from my browser after i press logout button.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you remove cookies also?

Comment: I tried remove cookie from my rails code, but its still there in my browser.

Comment: You have to clear cookies from your browser.

Comment: How to identify office 365 cookie and clear from Rails code...